# CMUS Error: opening audio device: No such device

Tags: server, sound, 13.10, hardware

I can't seem to play any audio with CMUS because it always gives the error:

```
CMUS Error: opening audio device: No such device
```

This is the output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High
Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device c892
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
        Memory at dff00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express
Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `alsa` as output, you need to set these:

```
set output_plugin=alsa
set dsp.alsa.device=default
set mixer.alsa.device=default
set mixer.alsa.channel=Master
```

Source: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cmus#Using_cmus_with_ALSA)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is incredibly old but I've run into the same issue and no where has an answer of any kind. To fix this problem I installed

```
sudo apt-get install libao-ocaml-dev
```

and that seems to have fixed my problem.

My symptoms were that I could play music if I was root but would the error described by OP if I wasn't. I needed to compile cmus from source because the version of cmus that I get from apt was unable to play some of my music because of an ffmpeg/avconv issue.

I didn't need to do anything special aside from install that library.

Answer (score -1):

cmus appears to default to the *pulseaudio* output plugin.

However the pulseaudio sound system is not necessarily installed on a headless server.

Try `:set output_plugin=alsa` or `:set output_plugin=ao` to switch to a supported backend.

Comment: thanks, i tried both but i still get the same error